# ZOC terminal 3270 for Mac

Tags: mainframe

I am using ZOC terminal on MAC OS to connect to mainframe 3270. There are two issues.

When i use 3278E or 3278ES, I am not able to login. Nothing happens when I enter region and press enter

When I use 3278 (standard), I am able to login to the region but the colors are static like it is not differentiating the keywords with color coding. Like comments should have a different color, exec sql, etc. but complete code looks green no matter how I change the colors from the settings. Hilite is on as well.

https://www.emtec.com/zoc/

Comment: Let us know the used ZOC version please.

Answer (score 0):

The colors are changed in the "Emulation" "Configuration" Menue. Or in the "Session Profile" for all TN3270 sessions.

I prefere a session specific configuration via "Configuration", enable "Override Session Profile settings" and you will see the button to change the colors als session settings below in the menue.

Check the used colour schema first, I prefere IBM PCOMM, sometimes QWS3270 is used and this looks strange, from my point of view.